# htaccess to Laravel public folder using https ONLY

Tags: .htaccess, https, laravel-5, web-hosting, public

My Laravel project is already inside in shared hosting server(i know what do you thinking...). And inside root folder i got a .htaccess file which has this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond $1 !^(public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This gives me good URL's without "public" but there is one case:
If i go:

```
www.example.com
```

so it always stays with URL www.....If i go:

```
https://www.example.com
```

it always stays with URL https://....

My question:
**How to make that the URL would always be https://www.example.com whatever I enter www or https first?**

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by putting following lines in the .htaccess files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in `.htacces` in your laravel root directory, it should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On

# enforce https
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# use public directory as root, but don't include it in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```